# UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext counterpart in desktop Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-graphics

I'm trying to crate a simple Mac paint application. On iOS I used UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext to update a UIImageView's image when touchesMoved. I'm now trying to active the same thing but on a Mac app, I want to do:

```
myNSImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

But that function does only exist on cocoa-touch and not within the cocoa framework, any tips on where/if I can find a similar function in Cocoa?

Thanks.

*Update*

Some additional code for completeness.

```
- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event
{

    NSInteger width = canvasView.frame.size.width;
    NSInteger height = canvasView.frame.size.height;

    NSGraphicsContext * graphicsContext = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
    CGContextRef contextRef = (CGContextRef) [graphicsContext graphicsPort];

    CGContextRef imageContextRef =  CGBitmapContextCreate(0, width, height, 8, width*4,    [NSColorSpace genericRGBColorSpace].CGColorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst); 

    NSPoint currentPoint = [event locationInWindow];

    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 49.0/255.0, 147.0/255.0, 239.0/255.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 1.0);

    CGContextBeginPath(contextRef);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(contextRef, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(contextRef, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextDrawPath(contextRef,kCGPathStroke);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(imageContextRef);
    NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef size:NSMakeSize(width, height)];
    canvasView.image = image;
    CFRelease(imageRef);
    CFRelease(imageContextRef);

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
```

}

The result I'm getting now that the painting works fine in the upper part of the view, but bot the rest. Like on this image (the red part should be the canvasView):

[image]

Comment: You are saying that it is "not working" - maybe you should refine and tell us what exactly the problem is.

Comment: @Till the problem is pretty clear, the function he mentions is iOS only and he's looking for a mac equivalent

Comment: @jrturton thanks for clarifying, adapted the question to point that out to everyone.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have added some additional code for completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSInteger width = 1024;
NSInteger height = 768;
CGContextRef contextRef =  CGBitmapContextCreate(0, width, height, 8, width*4, [NSColorSpace genericRGBColorSpace].CGColorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst); 

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 49.0/255.0, 147.0/255.0, 239.0/255.0, 1.0);
CGContextFillRect(contextRef, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height));

CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(contextRef);
NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef size:NSMakeSize(width, height)];
CFRelease(imageRef);
CFRelease(contextRef);
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't get that to work, i'm not "allowed" to create a CGBitmapContextCreate that is an CGImageRef.

Comment: I switched what I was doing, let me know if that will work for you. That should at least get you a valid context and nsimage.

Comment: Thanks, almost got it to work. I edited my answer with your code, but now I have another odd problem. :)

Comment: You didn't draw anything into the imageContextRef in your example, try using your imageContextRef in place of your contextRef

Comment: I have tried to change, eg. CGContextBeginPath(contextRef); to CGContextBeginPath(imageContextRef) and the other, but then it doesn't draw anything anywhere. hmm.

Comment: Give you the correct answer since it kinda seems to be the answer to my original question. Got it to work with help from this guide/example: juliuspaintings.co.uk/cgi-bin/paint_css/animatedPaint/

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> NSGraphicsContext * graphicsContext = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
> CGContextRef contextRef = (CGContextRef) [graphicsContext graphicsPort];
>
> CGContextRef imageContextRef =  CGBitmapContextCreate(0, width, height, 8, width*4,    [NSColorSpace genericRGBColorSpace].CGColorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
> ```

You're assuming, first off, that there is a current context, and then you create a separate context.

> ```
> CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 49.0/255.0, 147.0/255.0, 239.0/255.0, 1.0);
> CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 1.0);
>
> (etc.)
> ```

And then you draw into the context you assume exists, not the context you created.

> ```
> CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(imageContextRef);
> ```

And then you create an image from the context you created and never drew into.

Cut out the attempt to get `[NSGraphicsContext currentContext]` and its graphics port. You can't assume that there is a current context outside of `drawRect:`, anyway. Instead, draw into the context you created.

Comment: I have tried to replace contextRef with imageContextRef, but then it doesn't draw anything. I should clarify that that the drawing occurs in a NSViewController, I have created a custom subclass of NSImageView with the delegate methods mouseDown etc. I add this custom class as a subview to the view controllers view. I think it's strange that the drawing works outside the NSImageView (though I have to drag the mouse from it to fire the delegate methods) but not inside.

Comment: @Anders: “I have tried to replace contextRef with imageContextRef, but then it doesn't draw anything.” It doesn't draw anything now—not in the context you created and try to extract an image from. You're extracting an image from a context nothing has ever drawn into. Moreover, the context you *are* drawing into, you are not guaranteed to be able to get. You should only ever draw to the current context in a view's `drawRect:` method (or after *setting* the current context, which isn't necessary except in rare cases); anywhere else, the only correct way to draw is to a context you create.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your advice and tips. I will try to change my approach and move my drawing code to my NSImageView itself, and it's drawrect. Found this example that seems to work, http://juliuspaintings.co.uk/cgi-bin/paint_css/animatedPaint/010-NSView.pl. Thanks. :)